# why angularJS provide simple and common functions like angular.isDefined or angular.isFunction?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been thinking why angularJS provides simple functions like angular.isDefined or angular.isFunction or various other functions that are one-liner in native javascript.
Can someone clear this? why or why not to use these functions?

Comment: Because the creators of angular decided to include a few utility functions and `angular.isDefined(value)` is more straightforward than `typeof value !== 'undefined'`.

Comment: they could have provided a lot of functions that way, may be included complete lodash :P

Comment: These functions are more readable and handle conditions properly. Chances of errors are also reduced. Easy to use